# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

Cart is my model and its something like

```
//declaring a cart model for products to add

export class Cart{
    id:string;
    name:string;
    quantity:number;
    picture:string;
}
```

This is my service app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject  } from "@angular/core";
    import { WebStorageService, LOCAL_STORAGE } from "angular-webstorage-service";
    import { Cart } from "./models/cart.model";

    @Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
    export class AppService{
         key="Product";
        mycart:Cart[]=[];//creating a cart array
     constructor(@Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: WebStorageService) {

        }

     addtocart(id:string,name:string,quantity:number,picture:string){
      var newcart:Cart={id:id,name:name,quantity:quantity,picture:picture};
      this.mycart.push(newcart);//this gives me error
      this.storage.set(this.key, this.mycart);//saving cart to the local storage

     }   

    getproducts(){
        this.mycart= this.storage.get(this.key);
        console.log(this.mycart);
        return this.mycart;
    }



    }
```

I have gone through the answers but didnot find the relevant answer ,I am quite new to angular so dont have much idea about it any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Is `getproducts` being called first? If so, what is being logged?

Comment: yes I am calling getproducts on onInit()

Comment: And what is being logged? Setting it to an empty array isn't going to help if it's then set to null in `getproducts`

Comment: being logged?? where I am not getting u

Comment: In `getproducts`, you have a line: `console.log(this.mycart)`, which should log the value of `this.mycart` to the developer console.

Comment: null it sprinting null

Comment: do i have to use observables for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your console.log, you're setting it to null, hence why it prints `null`

You should check if `this.storage.get(this.key);` returns null, and only set `this.mycart` if it is not null. Try this:

```
getproducts(){
    cont storedCart = this.storage.get(this.key);
    if (storedCart != null) {
        this.mycart = storedCart;
    }
    return this.mycart;
}
```